# C# DataTable ImportRow issue

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

I have two `DataTable`s `t1` and `t2`. `t1` has data in it, `t2` is a newly created, empty table:

```
//fill `t1`
DataTable t2 = new DataTable();
for (int i = 0; i < t1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    if (t1.Rows[i][6].ToString().ToLower().StartsWith("xyz"))
    {
        t2.ImportRow(t1.Rows[i]);
    }
}
```

The above should theoretically work, though I have `0` columns in `t2` after the import loop.

```
t1 rows 13312 cols 25
t2 rows  3861 cols  0
```

I should have the same 25 columns, right?

Comment: make sure that you are importing the coulumn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That might be because before your `for` loop, `t2` is just a newly created `DataTable` object without any rows or columns. In the for loop you are importing rows and not getting any columns.

You might try adding the columns names on `t2` immediately after this declaration :

```
DataTable t2 = new DataTable();
```

Columns can be added using this :

```
t2.Columns.Add("colName", typeof(Double));
```

Also, make sure that the column name is identical with the one in `t1` and same goes for datatype too.

Not sure if this would work, but you can give it a try.

Comment: Well, I know how to add columns, but I'm sure you understand that I don't want to add 25 columns "manually".

Comment: Just for the chance of solving this, if you can try once putting it manually, that way atleast you would understand the cause so as to why this was happening.

Comment: Solved it with a for loop: `for (int i = 0; i < t1.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                Type type = t1.Columns[i].DataType;
                t2.Columns.Add(t.Columns[i].ColumnName, type);
            }`

Comment: Exactly. I was about to say that to you. Glad that it helped. :)